# 4 Horizontal ListViews Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart, android-listview

I  want to make use 4 listView Builder which scroll horizontally in a SingleChildScrollView but even after trying everything the page isn't scrolling vertically, can anyone help me with this.
Example :

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return FutureBuilder(
     future: getLibrayCourse(),
     builder:  (context,snapshot){
       if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
         return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
       }
       return Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
         child: Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           children: [
             Text("Free Video Courses",style: TextStyle(
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
               fontSize: 18
             ),),
             SizedBox(height:10),
             Container(
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
               child: ListView.builder(
                   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                   shrinkWrap: true,
                   itemCount: 10,
                   itemBuilder: (context, index){
                     return Card(
                       child: Text("YOYO"),
                     );
                   }),
             ),
             Text("Free Video Courses",style: TextStyle(
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                 fontSize: 18
             ),),
             SizedBox(height:10),
             Container(
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
               child: ListView.builder(
                   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                   shrinkWrap: true,
                   itemCount: 10,
                   itemBuilder: (context, index){
                     return Card(
                       child: Text("YOYO"),
                     );
                   }),
             ),
             Text("Free Video Courses",style: TextStyle(
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                 fontSize: 18
             ),),
             SizedBox(height:10),
             Container(
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
               child: ListView.builder(
                   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                   shrinkWrap: true,
                   itemCount: 10,
                   itemBuilder: (context, index){
                     return Card(
                       child: Text("YOYO"),
                     );
                   }),
             ),
             Text("Free Video Courses",style: TextStyle(
                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                 fontSize: 18
             ),),
             SizedBox(height:10),
             Container(
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
               child: ListView.builder(
                   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                   shrinkWrap: true,
                   itemCount: 10,
                   itemBuilder: (context, index){
                     return Card(
                       child: Text("YOYO"),
                     );
                   }),
             ),

           ],
         ),
       );
     },
   );
 }
```

If I use neverscrollable in my horizontal widget it will stop scrolling so that's an issue
I have tried adding Container height, using expanded etc still the problem persists

Comment: always show code, in your list views add physics never scrollable and should work fine

Comment: Have you tried flutter Slivers?

Comment: make ListView(shrinkWrap: true,
      primary: false,)

Comment: If I use or never scrollable physics my list view will stop the scroll and I want it to scroll.

Comment: @AsfarAli No, I haven't

Answer (score 0):

I copied and used your code and just moved the "column" to the "SingleChildScrollView". It worked for me, Both horizontal and vertical scrolling.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // your children
              ]
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I hope it was useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: getLibrayCourse(),
  builder:  (context,snapshot){
    if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          const Text("Free Video Courses",style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18
          ),),
          const SizedBox(height:10),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return const Card(
                    child: Text("YOYO"),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          const Text("Free Video Courses",style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18
          ),),
          const SizedBox(height:10),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return const Card(
                    child: Text("YOYO"),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          const Text("Free Video Courses",style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18
          ),),
          const SizedBox(height:10),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return const Card(
                    child: Text("YOYO"),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          const Text("Free Video Courses",style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18
          ),),
          const SizedBox(height:10),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return const Card(
                    child: Text("YOYO"),
                  );
                }),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Try this it will work properly.